# What is the use of subfile custom document class?

Tags: document-classes, subfiles

One way to use subfiles is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
...
\subfile{finename}
...
\end{document}
```

Another way is:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

And finally, we have this:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
```

I am trying to use a particular template where I need to use subfiles for easier management of the chapters. And I don't understand how these three differ and when to use what. Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is what you put in your main document. That is to say where you put your preamble and your chapters and organise your subfiles. The second two are what you put at the beginning of your subfiles (no preamble) depending on whether you have your subfiles in the same folder (`\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}`) or whether they are in a subfolder (`\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}`).

Comment: In the second two, if we do not set anything except the documentclass, why would it be more useful, or useful at all unless we do not (have to) care about the style?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean but if you're asking why we don't put a style preamble in the subfiles it's because the style for the main file would dictate the style for the subfiles. For example if you have put header formatting in your main file preamble this header formatting would also be used for the subfiles. So you don't need any preamble in the subfiles.